# Обработка вектора по три элемента за одну итерацию цикла

Tags: c++, vector, циклы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &string_to_cut, char delimiter)
{
        std::istringstream create_stream(string_to_cut);
        std::vector<std::string> parts;
        std::string part;

        while (std::getline(create_stream, part, delimiter))
        {
                parts.push_back(part);
        }

        return parts;
}

int main()
{
    std::string g = {"r,2,y,3,w,3"};
    std::vector<std::string> res = split(g,',');

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator d = res.begin(); d != res.end(); d=d+3)
    {
        int index = d-res.begin();
        std::cout << d[index+0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << d[index+1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << d[index+2] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
r
2
y
```

Вопрос: Почему не обрабатываются следующие три элемента?

Comment: Обращаться к элементам вектора не пробовали? `res[index+2]`

Comment: вообше то вы в цикле спокойно можете выйти за пределы вектора. Нужно использовать at() в таких случаях, с дальнейшей обработкой исключения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо

```
d[index+0]
```

нужно писать

```
res[index+0]
```

!

И еще - очень неприятное у вас условие - `d != res.end()` - а если количество элементов на 3 делиться не станет?...

Comment: а если количество элементов на 3 делиться не станет? я получу UB? Но что написать я не знаю...

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте - раз уж у вас вектор - использовал просто индексы. `for(size_t index = 0; index < res.size() /* тут смотрите сами на условие - можете обрезать, можете выводить что-то левое...*/; index += 3)...` - словом, как если бы это был обычный массив дляной `res.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно я не совсем понял вопрос, но такой вариант не подходит?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &string_to_cut, char delimiter)
{
        std::istringstream create_stream(string_to_cut);
        std::vector<std::string> parts;
        std::string part;

        while (std::getline(create_stream, part, delimiter))
        {
                parts.push_back(part);
        }

        return parts;
}

int main()
{
    std::string g = {"r,2,y,3,w,3"};
    std::vector<std::string> res = split(g,',');

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator d = res.begin(); d != res.end(); d=d+3)
    {
        std::cout << *(d+0) << std::endl;
        std::cout << *(d+1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << *(d+2) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно обрабатывать по три элемента вектора за одну итерацию цикла.

Comment: @GarfieldCat Обновил ответ